# bash: screen command: detach process renaming it and showing the changes in the gnome-system-monitor

Tags: bash, screen, process

```
screen -S myname -dm /processpath
```

or

```
screen -t myname -dm /processpath
```

does not affect the name displayed by gnome-system-monitor which is always "screen".
How can I change it?

Comment: Please check these answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167490/how-can-a-process-appear-to-have-different-name-in-ps-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a symlink to the screen binary like this:

```
ln -s `which screen` my_special_screen
```

And then run it:

```
./my_special_screen -dm /processpath
```

The `-t name` option is only useful when selecting a screen process to attach to with `screen -x` if you have multiple screen instances running.